# Hive create table command throwing SemanticException Line 0:-1 Invalid function 'IS NOT TRUE'

Tags: hive

My query is like

```
create table abc as select * from (select x,  (CASE WHEN ( y != '' and y is not null) THEN y ELSE z END ) AS testColumn from table1) q where q.testColumn is not null;
```

Whenever I am running this. It is giving me

```
SemanticException Line 0:-1 Invalid function 'IS NOT TRUE'
```

If I remove create table from the beginning it works, if I change column name from testColumn to x it works, if I change create table to insert into it works.

What is wrong with create table?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There had been patching on our cluster, due to which it was not working.
To make it work I need to set a property

```
set hive.cbo.enable=false;
```

After doing this my query worked.

Answer (score 0):

There are redundant `()`, I guess it causes error. Also `y != '' and y is not null` is redundant because if `y != ''`, it can not be NULL, so, `y != ''` is enough.

```
create table abc as 
select * 
from 
 (select x, 
         CASE WHEN y != '' THEN y ELSE z END AS testColumn 
    from table1
 ) q 
where q.testColumn is not null;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but it still gave me the same error
FAILED: SemanticException Line 0:-1 Invalid function 'IS NOT TRUE'